# ArgumentException for a localized app in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, resx, app.xaml

I have my app translated to 12 languages. But now I notice that while testing in emulator set to simplified chinese (zh-CN), it shows the `ArgumentException - Value does not fall within the expected range`. This error occurs at `InitializeComponent();` of App.xaml.cs. This error occurs only for Chinese and not for other languages only in the debug mode. The app does not terminate though, if I continue, it'l work as expected.

Does this seem familiar to anyone? Can this error be ignored? I have included the screenshot.

Alfah

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Screenshots of exceptions are practically worthless.  Is there an inner exception?  What is the stacktrace?  Better to catch the exception and get the default ToString() of it -- `catch(Exception ex){ var giveUsThis = ex.ToString(); }`

Comment: the exception occurs at App.g.cs inside the InitializeComponent()definition. So where do i put the catch??

Comment: You see that green line right there inside your screenshot?  The `try{` goes in the line before it (make room for it, don't just stick it on the end of `cnotentLoaded = true;`.  Then on line 51 you close the try with a left-facing bracket `}` and then on line 52 you add the catch as I commented before.  Place a breakpoint within the catch, and when the exception is thrown you'll be able to copy out the text of the exception.  Also, facepalm.